# Correct code for opening a file with an external editor

Tags: inno-setup

Is the following code it right or not and, if it is wrong, please correct it.

Note: I want to open the file with "WordPad.exe" not with "Microsoft Office Word" until if "Microsoft Office Word" is the default program.

My code:

```
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
 var
   S: AnsiString;
 begin
   // Show the contents of Readme.txt (non Unicode) in a message box
   ExtractTemporaryFile('Info.rtf');
   Result := True;
 end;

 procedure AboutButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
   ErrorCode: Integer;
 begin
  ShellExec('open', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Info.rtf'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait,
 ErrorCode);
 end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShellExec('open','Documentname'....);` will open with the program associated with the extension of the file.     If there is no program associated it will prompt you to select which program you want to view it with.

You could look for WordPad.exe and if it's found you could call `ShellExec` using the WordPad.EXE directly.   Then pass the documentName as a parameter.

**Updated with function to do this**

```
procedure OpenDocumentInWordPad(Document : String);
var
 WordPad : String;   
 ErrorCode : Integer;
begin
   // Typical Location on XP and later.
   WordPad := ExpandConstant('{pf}') + '\Windows NT\Accessories\WordPad.exe'
   // Find word pad
   if Not FileExists(WordPad) then
   begin
     // Location in Windows 95/98
     WordPad := ExpandConstant('{pf}') + '\Accessories\WordPad.exe'
     if Not FileExists(WordPad) then
     begin
       // Fall back to anything associated with document.
       WordPad := Document;
       Document := '';
     end;
   end;

   if not ShellExec('open',WordPad,Document,'',SW_SHOW,ewNoWait,ErrorCode) then
   begin
      MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode),mbError,MB_OK);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: i understand what you said in the end but i cant write the code to pass the documentName as a parameter. and i replace 'Documentname' with 'WordPad.exe' and the instlation open the WordPad but i cant make the WordPad open the temp file 'Info.rtf'

Comment: The third parameter in ShellExec is the Param where you can pass the document name.   I updated the answer to include a function that you can call that will do everything for you.

Comment: thank you for the code but
i want you to know that what i want exactly in this picture and maybe you know this program 
http://oi53.tinypic.com/dc8z7p.jpg 
i want to make like this instal file ( when the instal file open i can directly open the help file through WordPad through About Button.
1.open instal file 
2.the file "Info.rtf" sent to Temporary File
3.the user can open the file through WordPad through About Button

Comment: the code you give i modify it and the About Button open the WordPad  but give me an error 
"failed  to open Document".
 but i can write the all code to show you the code to tell me what is wrong
 so please if i can speak to you in any site let me write all what i need to tell you please tell me the name of this site cause i cant write all what i want to tell you here 
my mail is man_from_zero_hour@yahoo.com
if you have an account in face book please add me to speak with free

Comment: Stackoverflow is designed to keep things online.   If things are taken into side conversations others will not benefit.

Comment: Is this the code you have in the about button click now? `OpenDocumentInWordPad(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Info.rtf'));`

Comment: Once you get the about button working, ask another question on how to add a separate button to the wizard.

Comment: i like Stackoverflow but it didn't give me the all space to write all what i need to tell you and not all things can take in another question. it must be in this question cause if i do this i will ask 1000 question for one subject. so the problem is i need to show you my code but i cant write it all here.

Comment: i make it and i open the file in the Temporary File through WordPad through About Button but i modify the code you give me. 
i will capture a picture to all code to show you it. 
this is the picture of all the code  http://i51.tinypic.com/2j32uzo.jpg
thank you for helping me and i will ask many question and i want you to answer it :))